# The QGIS delete key does not work

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.8

[image]I am inquiring about the vertex deletion of qgis.

When you delete a link vertex, select Delete vertex and press the DELETE key to delete it. Deletion does not take place.

Is there any problem?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful to better understand. Are you hitting the delete key on the keyboard?

Comment: Does the **Backspace** key work? This should have the same function as the **Del** key.

Comment: @Techie_Gus
If you press delete key, there is no response and no error message is displayed. All other shortcut keys work fine.

Comment: @Joseph 
Both the Backspace key and DELETE Keys are inoperative. 
All other shortcut keys work fine.

Comment: Are you clicking the node tool before selecting the vertex?

Comment: @Techie_Gus
Yes, Used after activating node tool.

Comment: I fail to see what is going on. Are you able to edit the layer normally, i.e. add/delete/move features and save your edits? Is this happening with any layer you try to edit this way or is it just one layer?

Answer (score 1):

It appears have not selected the feature. It should be yellow once selected

1. Ensure edit mode is enabled on the layer
2. Ensure the attribute toolbar is visible (view, toolbars, attributes)
3. Find this button
   [image: Select by area or click] It is called select by area or click
4. Now you can select and delete the feature with your mouse and delete key
5. Save your edits

Comment: If you are editing vertices, as in this case, you do not need to select the feature. The vertex that you wish to delete should be in blue just as the screen shot shows. In more recent versions of QGIS, if you have a vertex selected, you should also see the Vertex Editor. That will highlight (in blue) the vertex that you wish to delete. As to why that's not happening ... I'm not sure.